# 'where' vs 'as where' - Relative pronouns?

Tags: difference, relative-pronouns

> Other torts include defamation (libel and slander), private nuisance, assault, false imprisonment, trespass and passing off. Passing off occurs where, through icons or logos or website styles, a business is conducted in such a way as to mislead the public into believing that its goods or services are those of another more famous business, **as where** a design or packaging trade mark is falsely used.

Source: P9, Law: the Basics, Gary Slapper

1. What are the similarities and differences? What would happen if I simply wrote **where**?
2. With which definition does [as](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/as)  accord? What does **as** mean here?

Answer (score 1):

The *as* is used in the sense *as is the case* to restrict the sense of what follows it.

Without the *as* the following clause would be taken to define *mislead &c*, implying that *passing off*  occurs **only** in instances *where a design or packaging trade mark is falsely used*. *As* marks such false use as merely an example of *passing off*; this leaves room for the term to embrace other misleading practices such as using a corporate name very similar to a competitor's or using a celebrity's picture to imply that the celebrity endorses one's product.

Comment: +1. Thank you. Would you please pinpoint which definition in that link applies here? I'd guess Conjunction: 2(.0).

Comment: Will you please to respond in your answer, and not as a comment?